# Error in extension for webdriver

Tags: selenium, c#-4.0, selenium-webdriver, pageobjects

I'm writing a framework with page object. I have a lot of ajax, so in order to get rid of ugly Thread.sleep(5000), I created an extension method, which waits until an element is visible and clicks on it, otherwise it throws an error. But I suspect that there is an error in my code, because it always thrown an error.

```
public static void WaitForVisible(this IWebElement element, int timeoutSec = 10)
        {
            var startTime = DateTime.Now;
            while ((DateTime.Now - startTime) > TimeSpan.FromSeconds(timeoutSec))
            {
                if (element.Displayed)
                    return;
            }
            throw new Exception("Element wasn't displayed after '" + timeoutSec + "'!");
        }
        public static void ClickWithWait(this IWebElement element)
        {
            WaitForVisible(element);
            element.Click();
        }
```

Could you please tell what am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

Please try this method.

```
WebDriverWait wait = new WebDriverWait(driver, 10);


try { 
WebElement element= wait.until(ExpectedConditions.visibilityOfElementLocated(By.id("someid")));

}
catch(Exception e)
{ 
System.out.println(e.getMessage()); 
}
```

Comment: Actually, I don't understand how it can help me. Not all elements on a page have ids and, actually, I prefer finding by XPath. That's why I decided to write an extension method which allows to path IWebElement regardless of how it has been located